# How to use remote SharedObject in AS3 and Red5 -- Second Attempt

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, red5, shared-objects

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903298/how-to-use-remote-sharedobject-in-as3-and-red5) in StackOverflow seven months ago, but apparently no one could give me a satisfactory answer. I have searched the entire Internet to no avail.  So I am posting this here again, in the hope that this can be solved for the benefits of all. Please bear with me as I really need this to be done.

Here is my code so far.

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.events.SyncEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var nc:NetConnection; 
var so:SharedObject;
nc = new NetConnection(); 
nc.client = { onBWDone: function():void{} };
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus); 
nc.connect("rtmp://localhost:1935/live");

var t = new TextField();
addChild(t);

var c = new TextField();
c.y=100;
c.text="SET SO";
addChild(c);
c.addEventListener('click',sd);
function sd(e:MouseEvent):void{
   so.setProperty("total",3);
   //so.setDirty("total");
   //trace("a"+so.data.total);
}

function onNetStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void{ 
   if(event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success"){ 
      so = SharedObject.getRemote("shObj",nc.uri);
      so.addEventListener(SyncEvent.SYNC,syncHandler);
      so.connect(nc);
      so.setProperty("total",2);
   } 
}
function syncHandler(event:SyncEvent):void{
   if (so.data.total) {
      t.text = so.data.total;
   } 
}
```

I expected to see the number 3 as I clicked the text 'SET SO'. However, it seems that syncHandler is never fired. What should I do to make it work? Have I missed out something? Was the server correctly linked?

Comment: `public static function getRemote(name:String, remotePath:String = null, persistence:Object = false, secure:Boolean = false):SharedObject`, so there is this property `persistence:Object (default = false)`. True, false, or obj.. For obj - `A full or partial local path to the shared object indicates that the shared object is persistent on the client and the server.` Maybe this will help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use remote SharedObject in AS3 and Red5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903298/how-to-use-remote-sharedobject-in-as3-and-red5)

Comment: obvious duplicate, you should update original question!!